# I want to combine the list and find(), but I don't know how to merge them

Tags: c++

Please see the part where the `find()` function is called. (I ran it in Visual Studio.)

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    
    //Implementing the find()
    /*
    bool Find(const Stu & a); {
        return (*it).name;
    }
    */
   
    list<Astu>::iterator that;
    //that = astu.begin();
    //that = find(astu.begin(), astu.end(), (*it).name);

    for (it = stu.begin(); it != stu.end(); it++) {
        that = find_if(astu.begin(), astu.end(), (*it).name);
        if (that != astu.end()) {
            all = astu.erase(all);
            all++;
        }
        else
            all++;
    }
    /*
    //Filter absenteeism from the total student roster
    for (it = stu.begin(); it != stu.end(); it++) {
        for (all = astu.begin(); all != astu.end();) {
            if (!strcmp((*all).name, (*it).name)) {
                //Delete attendees and latecomers from the list
                all = astu.erase(all);
            }
            else
                all++;
        }
    }
    */

    
    cout << "---------------------\n결석자: " << endl;
    //이름순으로 정렬
    astu.sort(SizeComp2);
    //결석자들 출력
    for (all = astu.begin(); all != astu.end(); all++) {
        cout << "이름: " << (*all).name << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> C2064 error occurred: Term does not evaluate to a function that takes
> 1 argument.

[image]

Even with `find_if()` in this code, there is a problem. The bool() part in the comment was used for the `find_if` object, but it doesn't seem to be used well here.

I deleted the part where there was no problem as a result of debugging. You must use an unconditional list, not a vector.

Where should I fix it?

Comment: `find_if` takes a predicate function. `find` takes a value.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument to [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) is a *function*.

You could use a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) as the function:

```
auto that = find_if(astu.begin(), astu.end(), [it](Astu const& astu)
                   {
                       return astu.name == it->name;
                   });
```

<sub>[This assumes that `Astu::name` is a `std::string`]</sub>